# does flutter dart's http request have tls support?

Tags: ssl, dart, https, aws-api-gateway

I do not know much about computer networks but I've been dabbling with flutter and aws lambda.

I have a flutter (dart) code that uses http package to make an http request like the following:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http

final response = await http.get('https://<address to my lambda function via api gateway>');
final body = response.body;
```

Looking at the http package in pub.dev, it says that the package is a `A composable, Future-based library for making HTTP requests.` and does not say anything about TLS(SSL). However, the url I provided in the above code is `https` generated by aws API gateway. So my question is, in the above code, is it using https or http? If it is using http, it is not secure hence, i need to add another layer of security to prevent hackers such as Man in the middle attack. If it is https, does that mean the data that gets sent is encrypted via TLS, hence I do not need any sort of asymmetric encryption between the client and the server?

Comment: It support HTTPS. About the security aspect you should have some kind of authentication if you want to restrict who are going to access the API.

Comment: [HttpClient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) from `dart:io` mentions about https support but couldn't find for [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

Comment: @dev-aentgs afaik the http package is just a wrapper around `HttpClient` (for dartvm and flutter) and `XMLHttpRequest` (when compiled to javascript)

Comment: @julemand101 so to be clear, as long as I provide an url with https, dart's http.get will execute https protocol, not http. So I enable TLS/SSL encryption just by providing https url? But if I provide http url, then it uses http protocol so it becomes insecure?

Comment: so sending user id and password via dart's http package should be safe?

Comment: @MoneyBall Yes, if the address contains HTTPS it is fine. If you really want to be sure you should make the endpoint so it can only be accessed over HTTPS (block port 80 where HTTP are running). In that way, it does not even matter what Dart does. If the connection are not encrypted it will not connect.